# Multivariate LSTM walk-forward fitting

Tags: python, machine-learning, keras, lstm

I have an LSTM model that was trained on the multi-feature daily dataset and predicts the target feature's value one day in the future.

How should I retrain the model each day as the new data becomes available? Should I rerun the `model.fit` with the full dataset (which gets updated each day) like in the example below?

```
model.fit(x_train, y_train, epochs=50, batch_size=20, 
          validation_data=(x_test, y_test), verbose=2, shuffle=False)
```

Or I can call `model.fit` only with the newly available data?

```
# run at the beggining once
model.fit(x_train, y_train, epochs=50, batch_size=20, 
          validation_data=(x_test, y_test), verbose=2, shuffle=False)
# run every day as the new data gets available.
model.fit(x_yesterday, x_yesterday)
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are using Keras, I would use `train_on_batch` See this previous question for the answer: [What is the use of train_on_batch() in keras?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49100556/what-is-the-use-of-train-on-batch-in-keras)