# Use fit or train_on_batch in LSTM training

Tags: python, tensorflow

A LSTM layer is a recurrent neural network that uses previous data to predict (more or less). My question comes in order to train it. Due to its use in a time series, it is better to use `model.fit()` to fit all at once (suitable in my PC) or `train_on_batch()` to upgrade the gradient simulating a time series?

Comment: There is no difference, because each sample in your batch is one time series.

Comment: @Dr.Snoopy so there is no difference in fitting the whole dataset at once and using `train_on_batch()` with each sample in an incremental learning?

Comment: Please can you refer [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49100556/what-is-the-use-of-train-on-batch-in-keras) thread may help you. Thanks!