# How to choose a batch for train_on_batch?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, deep-learning, training-data

I was reading into how the `train_on_batch` function in Keras works. My understanding is that it only trains on a single batch. Someone on here said that if you feed in 10 images, and your batch size is 2, your network will only train on two images. Which two images in particular, just the first two? Once the batch is chosen, does the training work the same as in `fit`?

For context, I'm trying to reproduce the function from scratch.

Comment: for all_data in epoch*all_data: for batch(as all_data[:batch]) in all_data: Calculate loss to update.

Comment: As state in documentation ```train_on_batch: Runs a single gradient update on a single batch of data.```  Please refer to that answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49100556/what-is-the-use-of-train-on-batch-in-keras . What is most important is that using ```train_on_batch``` you dont focus on ```batch_size```, just update gradients on provided sample, in your case it ll be 10 images.

Comment: @senh How would it be different than `fit()` then?

Answer (score 0):

`fit()` - Trains the model for a fixed number of epochs (iterations on a dataset) whereas

`train_on_batch()` - Runs a single gradient update on a single batch of data.

Please find more details on both model functions terminologies in [this](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/Model#fit) link.

You can get some more understanding with [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48550201/what-does-train-on-batch-do-in-keras-model) answer.